# Games run way too fast. Setting affinity doesn't work at all. How in the world do I make the game run normal speed?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, day-of-defeat, operation-flashpoint-dragon-rising

Games like Day Of Defeat and Operation Flashpoint Dragon Rising run way too fast (x2) but even if I change the affinity in the task manager so the games use only one CPU, there is no noticeable change whatsoever and the game continues to be in fast forward and unplayable.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Hi Joe, I noticed you cross posted this question to Super User.  Please only question to one site.  If it belongs on another we'll migrate it there for you.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try Mo'Slo, I remember it being quite effective. The basic version is available [here](http://www.hpaa.com/moslo/basic.asp) for free.

In case of DOS-based games, using DOSBox is I believe even better approach, as it allows you to precisely control the CPU cycles (speed) in its configuration files.

---

Update - I just asked a similar question yesterday and was quite satisfied with the answer. You might want to take a look if still interested - [How to limit/lock framerate (FPS) like in FRAPS video-recording mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113040/how-to-limit-lock-framerate-fps-like-in-fraps-video-recording-mode)

Comment: +1 for DOSBox. When some companies re-release their DOS games they bundle DOSBox with it - it's that awesome.

Comment: These are games running in Steam. Half life 2 engine, and some other engines, non-dos.

Answer (score 4):

Are you over-clocking at all?

A quick look around the net and most problems like yours with games running the source engine are caused by the system being over-clocked.

Maybe check in your bios. Some motherboards (like my old ASUS) will have some form of automatic over-clocking in place by default. If you turn that off you may find it runs fine!