# How to limit/lock framerate (FPS) like in FRAPS video-recording mode?

Tags: windows-xp, last-bronx

Is there a way to limit or lock framerate (FPS) to a certain maximum value, just like FRAPS is able to do while recording? I am trying to play Last Bronx on Win XP, but the game runs way too fast, even with Frameskip set to "None" (there is no framelimit option).

I had some success experimenting with FRAPS (which is presumably notorious for decreasing games performance) as it has an option to lock framerate for recording purposes. It works great and locks to 60 FPS this way, but recording is tedious, takes space and I have to remember to delete my movies after playing (even if only to ensure nobody sees me getting regularly pummelled heh).

Is there a way to lock framerate in FRAPS without recording (i.e. automatically redireting recorded AVI > dev/null or something similar)? If not, is there any other software or way to lock game's framerate?

I already tried forcing vsync in AMD CCC, with no effect. Same for disabling Direct3D/DirecrDraw acceleration using dxdiag. I also launched some cpu-consuming software in background, but this usually results in stuttering and reduces playability more effectively than the framerate. Last Bronx is not DOS-based, so apparently DOSBox is also not an option.

Comment: *Last Bronx* is an ancient title; It came out when Windows 95 was brand-new. It probably doesn't use DirectX or even 3D hardware, so changing your D3D settings or using force vsync option (which is for 3D-accelerated apps, not 2D or software 3D apps) probably won't work.

Comment: Come on, it's not THAT ancient! Wiki says they released it for PC 1997, and packaging specifies DirectX 5 and Direct3D-compatible video card as minimum requirements.

Comment: DX1 was only released in 1995 two years before (nevermind that games are in development long before release), and lots of game developers avoided it like the plague at first. In Windows games terms, it *is* ancient. ;) But knowing it's a DX5 game is very useful info for the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Fraps has no option to enable it outside of recording.

You could use [Dxtory](http://dxtory.com/v2-download-en.html) though to lock your fps. It is a tool to play games that run too fast because they do improper timing and are actually "timed" by their framerate. Which is a horrible design idea btw, if I might add that.

There is also a comprehensive guide over at the [Steam Forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1820131).

---

An alternative to this is [Bandicam](http://www.bandicam.com/product/game_recording_program_setting/). On the feature overview on the download page it says that this feature is freely available even in the trial edition which is not restricted by time.

[image]

---

To make this answer complete:

For NVIDIA Users there is a Tool called "[NVIDIA Inspector](http://downloads.guru3d.com/NVIDIA-Inspector-1.94-download-2612.html)" which can do FPS limiting too and that Tool is actually free.

Comment: Dxtory works good! Unfortunately it's not free or affordable (license seems to be around 30-40 USD), which is a bit problematic for such limited use. Is there any freeware or cheaper alternative?

Comment: @acalypso Updated answer. There are some "hackish" programs out there without any website and only downloadable via mediafire and similar sites, but I don't trust them.

Comment: Bandicam is exactly what I was looking for! Works much smoother than Dxtory in my opinion. Trial version has significant recording restrictions, but the FPS control works perfectly and presumably it is not time limited. It seems to get some good opinions too, so might consider buying a 40 USD license too. Who would have thought gameplay recoding software is the way to go for playing old Windows 95/98 games (gonna try this for GTA1!) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RadeonPro is free and will allow you to  lock the framerate. (on the tweaks tab) Not sure if it works with DX5 though. :/

http://www.radeonpro.info/download/

Comment: Unfortunately the installer refuses to work, stating Win NT 6 is required. This means Vista and newer OS, so can't really test it.